# Windows 10 Desktop wakes up automatically, falls into a "heavy" sleep

Tags: windows-10

Here's my problem. I'm running Windows 10 Build 10586 on a computer that I built. When I put it in sleep mode, it goes to sleep fine. However, after what seems like a random time (usually no more than 10 minutes), it will wake up. My monitors stay black, and after about 10 seconds, it goes back to sleep. When it goes back to sleep, its a "heavier" sleep though. If I wake the computer, it will be back at the splash screen that you see when you first turn your computer on instead of just resuming on the desktop. It takes longer than normal to wake up when this happens.

I've adjusted various power option settings and disabled some network settings (such as Wake on Pattern Match, Wake on Magic Packet, and disabling the ability for my network card to wake my computer) and it still does it.

I should also note that this started happening after I got an uninterrupted power supply. However, I've switched back to normal power strip and it is still occurring.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your computer is rebooting, not going to sleep, likely caused by a crashed by the initial sleep state.

Comment: That sounds like a possibility.  Do you know of a way to determine if this really is the problem?

Comment: Check "View reliability history" under Maintenance in the Security and Maintenance control panel applet. Are there any events that say that "Windows stopped working"? Alternatively, do your event logs report a bugcheck of any kind?

Comment: Looking at the Reliability Monitor, there are some events saying "Windows was not properly shut down" and another that is occurring a lot is titled DipAwayMode.exe with a summary saying "Stopped Working."  I believe the DipAwayMode.exe is part of the software I use (AI Suite III) to control fan speeds, power usage, etc.  I think its this DipAwayMode executable that may be causing my problem, as the amount of times this event has stopped working is significantly higher than the Windows one.  So far, uninstalling and reinstalling the most update version of the AI Suite software did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something unusual but seems to have fixed the problem.  Under the System Settings in the Power Options, I unchecked the "Turn on fast startup (recommended)."  I put my computer into sleep mode, and it hasn't turned back on by itself for some hours now.

I wouldn't have thought this would affect sleep mode in anyway, but it appears to have solved my issue.